# customizing sencha yes no combo within a specific panel without affecting parent combo box

Tags: extjs, combobox

I need to customize the yes no combo within a specific panel, local to the panel without affecting the parent yesnocombo box configuration. Is there a way to do this?

I am referring to the form I posted earlier in another thread in the Sencha forums, but no one has answered. The url is: 
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthre...ng-Sencha-form

I tried this:

```
var myNewStore =[
"", "Yes", "Revoke"];
Ext.define('YesNoCombo',{
  extend:'Ext.form.ComboBox',
  store:myNewStore,
  value:'',
  emptyText:'Select...',
  labelalign:'left',
  labelWidth:550,
  inputWidth:80,
  allowBlank:true,
  listeners:{
    select:function(comp,record,index){
      if(comp.getVelue() == "" || comp.getVale() ==="&nbsp")
        comp.setValue(null);
    }
  }
});
```

but this broke the format of the form.

Is there a way to create a local combo with custom variables like this:

```
var UserForm_BlahBlahBlah=Ext.create('YesNoCombo', {
  name:"UserForm_BlahBlahBlah",
  fieldLabel:"BlahBlahBlah",
  values:" Yes" "Revoke",
});
```

I tried this but it will not work. But you get the idea- It is just creating a local extension within a specific panel with new values.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way that sencha implements customizing the combo box with out affecting the parent class?

Regards,
umbre gachoong

Answer (score 1):

You can easily extend `Ext.form.ComboBox` class and create your own combo box class. Then you can use your combobox in forms.

In the exmaple I create custom combobox by using its `xtype` which I defined by `alias: 'widget.yesNoCombo'`. You can also create instance of custom combobox by `var combo = Ext.create('YesNoCombo');`

```
    Ext.define('YesNoCombo',{
        alias: 'widget.yesNoCombo',
        extend:'Ext.form.ComboBox',
        store: ["No", "Yes", "Revoke"],
        emptyText:'Select...',
        allowBlank:true
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items:[
            {
                xtype: 'yesNoCombo',
                fieldLabel:'Yes No Label',
                name: 'combo',
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Another field',
                name: 'anotherField',
            },
        ]
    });
```

See this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/210

Comment: Thanks! I created a new store and invoked it in the specific area and it worked! See http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?277773-customizing-yes-no-combo-within-a-specific-panel-without-affecting-parent-combo-box&p=1017068#post1017068